# To keep tooltip element in opened state till the time tooltip is hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular7

I have a box, once we hover over the box a tooltip appears and when I go inside the tooltip, the tooltip remains open.

For box on **left side** the tooltip will open to its **right**.

For box on **right side** the tooltip will open to its **left**.

This scenario works for the left side box but isn't working for the right side box.

```
else if (e.type === 'mouseleave' && e.clientX < x.right) {
 this.modelStyle = {
   display: 'none'
  };
 }
```

What changes in mouse leave function should be made in order to handle tooltip hovering functionality for the right side box same behaviour as for the left side box tooltip is being handled.

**Stackblitz link**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obzqsk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

modelStyle: any = {
  display: 'none'
};
modelClickedStyle: any = {
  display: 'none'
};
modalStyleClikedFlag;

addClickEvent(e) {
 let x = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
if (e.type === 'click') {
  this.modalStyleClikedFlag = true;
  this.modelClickedStyle = {
    top: 0 + 'px',
    left: 0 + 'px',
    height: 900 + 'px',
    width: 90 + '%',
    display: 'block'
   };
  }
else if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
  this.modalStyleClikedFlag = false;
  if(((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) - x.right) >200 ){
    this.modelStyle = {
       top: 0 + 'px',
       left: x.right + 'px',
       height: screen.height + 'px',                          
       width: 65 +'%',
       display: 'flex'
                       };
   }else{
     this.modelStyle = {
      top: 0 + 'px',
      right:((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) x.left) + 'px',
      height: screen.height + 'px',                                   
      width: 65 +'%',
      display: 'flex'
        };
     }
}
else if (e.type === 'mouseleave' && e.clientX < x.right) {
  this.modelStyle = {
    display: 'none'
  };
}
}

onPopEvent() {
  this.modelStyle = {
  display: 'none'
};
}

}
```

html

```
<div class="box1" (mouseenter)="addClickEvent($event)" 
 (mouseleave)="addClickEvent($event)" (click)="addClickEvent($event)">
 On click
</div>

<div class="box2" (mouseenter)="addClickEvent($event)" 
 (mouseleave)="addClickEvent($event)" (click)="addClickEvent($event)">
 On click
</div>


<fs-modal [ngStyle]="modalStyleClikedFlag ? modelClickedStyle :modelStyle" 
 (mouseleave)="onPopEvent($event)">
</fs-modal>
```

Comment: @joyBlanks, Answer is not there in that post :) and also I have edited the stackblitz link , it would be great if you could help , thanks

Comment: The issue is, the logic in mouseleave which I am using e.clientX < x.right for tooltip of left side box also satisfies for the right side box tooltip and it also closes , how to handle both sides tooltip hovering.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw91du is this what you are looking for??

Comment: I think yes but the only issue in your answer is the tooltip doesn't go off if I go out of the box, I want same for right  box as I have for left box in my stackblitz link

Comment: ok you have given settiimeout as well, I think this is correct :) , thanks , please post answer I'll accept :)

Comment: But I think the tooltip for right side box doesn't close until I go inside the popup agian and then come out, I mean if I hover over the box and without going inside the popup I come out the popup should close , it satisfies the second condition if I am hovering over the popup then it stays opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a timeout and then if the user intends to enter the box it will be open

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  active = null;
  modelStyle: any = {
    display: 'none'
  };
  modelClickedStyle: any = {
    display: 'none'
  };
  modalStyleClikedFlag;

  addClickEvent(e) {
    let x = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (e.type === 'click') {
      this.modalStyleClikedFlag = true;
      this.modelClickedStyle = {
        top: 0 + 'px',
        left: 0 + 'px',
        height: 900 + 'px',
        width: 90 + '%',
        display: 'block'
      };
    }
    else if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
      this.modalStyleClikedFlag = false;
      if (((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) - x.right) > 200) {
        this.modelStyle = {
          top: 0 + 'px',
          left: x.right + 'px',
          height: screen.height + 'px',
          width: 65 + '%',
          display: 'flex'
        };
      } else {
        this.modelStyle = {
          top: 0 + 'px',
          right: ((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) - x.left) - 200 + 'px',
          height: screen.height + 'px',
          width: 65 + '%',
          display: 'flex'
        };

      }
    }
    else if (e.type === 'mouseleave' && e.clientX < x.right) {
      if (this.active) {
        clearTimeout(this.active);
      }
      this.active = setTimeout(() => {
        this.modelStyle = {
          display: 'none'
        };
      }, 1000)
    }
  }

  onPopEvent(e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
      if (this.active) {
        clearTimeout(this.active);
      }
    } else if (e.type === 'mouseleave') {
      this.modelStyle = {
        display: 'none'
      };
    }
  }

}
```

StackBlitz for your reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw91du

Comment: This is me pointing to you in the right direction . You have to work out whats best for your users.

Comment: this is because of your incorrect borders check the updated SB https://angular-yw91du.stackblitz.io

Comment: It closes in a second. since the tooltip is some distance apart the mouse leave closes the tooltip. the left one stays coz the tooltip and left box are almost together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199160/discussion-between-enthu-and-joyblanks).